# Prevent Mathematica to automatically evaluate Manipulate at start

Tags: evaluation

I'm using an initialization cell to import a lot of data:

```
data = Import[myFiles];
```

and then I use a custom function to display this data with Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[customFunction[data,variable],{variable,{0,1}}]
```

I have to keep these two commands in two seperate cells, because importing the data in `customFunction` each time I manipulate `variable` would take a lot of time.

The problem is, when I start my notebook, `Manipulate` is evaluated automatically and sends a lot of error messages, because `data` is not defined. I know it might go against what Manipulate is made for, but is there a way to prevent Manipulate from being evaluated until I import my data for the first time?

Comment: You could always make the importing cell an initialisation cell?

Comment: Can't you use `SaveDefinitions->True` ?

Comment: @Verbeia no because initialization cells are evaluated only just before a first cell is evaluated in the notebook, whereas `Manipulate` is evaluated right away.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I didn't know this option and it looks like it does what I want! So basically with this option I would only need to evaluate `data = Import[myFiles];` once and then again only if `myFiles` change? Is there a bad side-effect of saving a lot of information with `SaveDefinitions -> True` (in terms of time for the notebook to load for example)?

Comment: @su1 My understanding is that with that option `Manipulate` will remember the last state it was in, including all controls. As to performance issues, you just have to try and see.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Hi, b.gatessucks ! Currently, none of the answers actually answer the op's question "How to prevent Mathematica to automatically evaluate Manipulate at start?". And this is what I want to know! I don't want some of my manipulate run automatically at the startup of a notebook, because they are time consuming. I didn't find the option. Do you know how to do it？ Thank you

Comment: @matheorem Hi, have a look at `"ToggleDynamicUpdating"` perhaps ?

Answer (score 8):

I see three methods:

**1. ValueQ**

Keep the two separate cells and make the last one depend on `data`. If `data` has no value for any reason, the `Manipulate`-part won't be evaluated at all. For sake of consistency, I've included a first cell that clears any previous value of `data`, but this (just as the second cell) should be only evaluated once, at the start of your session.

```
 In[1] := ClearAll[data];

 In[2] := data = Import[myFiles];

 In[3] := If[ValueQ[data], Manipulate[...], "do nothing"]
```

**2. Initialization option**

Create just one cell, but put in the option `Initialization` which ensures that its content gets evaluated before the body of `Manipulate` is displayed:

```
  Manipulate[
     customFunction[data, variable], {variable, {0, 1}},
     Initialization :> (data = Import[myFiles])]
```

Though note, that his will load `myFiles` each time the `Manipulate` is re-displayed. If `myFiles` is large, this imposes quite an overhead every time.

**3. Initialization cell**

Keep the two cells and make the first one an initialization cell (like Verbeia said) (right click on cell bracket > **Initialization Cell**. From now on, any time you open this notebook, the initialization cell will be evaluated automatically.

Comment: Probably the first option would be the best for me. "Initialization option" is not good enough because `myFiles` take a few seconds to be imported, so it's better to import them only once. "Initialization cells" are not good enough because they are not evaluated automatically at start, they are evaluated only after I evaluate any cell and click "Yes" when asked if I want to evaluate all initialization cells, whereas the cell containing `Manipulate` is evaluated automatically!

Answer (score 4):

This did it for me:

```
Manipulate[customFunction[data,variable], {variable,{0,1}}, SaveDefinitions->True]
```

No performance side affects here.

Thanks to user `b.gatessucks` for providing this answer in the question's comments.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative which encapsulates everything in a graphical user interface and needs no global variables:

```
longimport = (Pause[5]; RandomReal[]) &;
Manipulate[
 If[data =!= None,
  Manipulate[customFunction[data, variable], {variable, {0, 1}}],
  Panel["Please load data!"]
  ],
 {{data, None}, None},
 Control[Row[{
    Button[Dynamic[If[data === None, "Load Data", "Reload Data"]], 
     data = longimport[], Method -> "Queued"],
    Button["Clear Data", data = None, Method -> "Queued"]
    }]],
 AppearanceElements -> None
 ]
```

You can of course use whatever other expression you prefer instead of `None` to indicate that the data has not yet been imported. The custom `longimport` function is of course just for testing purposes, you could also let the user select a filename and then import within such a function...